# App engine update breaks CloudStorage in dev php env

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

After todays update (release: "1.9.18".) of GoogleAppEngineLauncher,  CloudStorageTool now throws an exception it didn't before.
This is the exception thrown:

```
google\appengine\runtime\RPCFailedError: Remote implementation for app_identity_service.GetAccessToken failed.
```

The trace looks like this:

```
google_appengine/php/sdk/google/appengine/api/app_identity/AppIdentityService.php@182
google_appengine/php/sdk/google/appengine/ext/cloud_storage_streams/CloudStorageClient.php@329
google_appengine/php/sdk/google/appengine/ext/cloud_storage_streams/CloudStorageUrlStatClient.php@132
google_appengine/php/sdk/google/appengine/ext/cloud_storage_streams/CloudStorageUrlStatClient.php@63
google_appengine/php/sdk/google/appengine/ext/cloud_storage_streams/CloudStorageStreamWrapper.php@358
```

Reproducing code:

```
$filename = 'test.txt';
$bucket_name = google\appengine\api\cloud_storage\CloudStorageTools::getDefaultGoogleStorageBucketName();
file_exists( 'gs://'.$bucket_name.'/'.$filename );
```

I'm running the GoogleAppEngineLauncher, PHP runtime. On mac OSX 10.10.2 and testing locally.

Has anybody else experienced this? Does anyone have a workround?

Comment: Same happens here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28626222/using-gcs-in-gae-local-devserver

Answer (score 3):

As said in the comment [Using GCS in GAE Local devserver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28626222/using-gcs-in-gae-local-devserver/28630207#28630207) there is an issue with 1.9.18. They advise to downgrade to 1.9.17 with this [link](https://storage.googleapis.com/appengine-sdks/featured/GoogleAppEngineLauncher-1.9.17.dmg)

Answer (score -1):

Update: As of March 5th, 2105 this was fixed in the public release of 1.9.18, which may be a simpler way to get the fix.