# Unable to start App Engine application after updating it via Google Cloud SDK

Tags: python, windows, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

Recently, I have updated Google App Engine from 1.9.17 to 1.9.18 via [Google Cloud SDK](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/) by using command 'gcloud components update' in Windows 7 64 bit. After that I wasn't able to start any project using the App Engine launcher. Getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\dev_appserver.py", line 83, in <module>
    _run_file(__file__, globals())
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\dev_appserver.py", line 79, in _run_file
    execfile(_PATHS.script_file(script_name), globals_)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\devappserver2.py", line 36, in <module>
    from google.appengine.tools.devappserver2 import dispatcher
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\dispatcher.py", line 29, in <module>
    from google.appengine.tools.devappserver2 import module
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\module.py", line 71, in <module>
    from google.appengine.tools.devappserver2 import vm_runtime_factory
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\vm_runtime_factory.py", line 25, in <module>
    from google.appengine.tools.devappserver2 import vm_runtime_proxy
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\vm_runtime_proxy.py", line 29, in <module>
    from google.appengine.tools.devappserver2 import log_manager
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\log_manager.py", line 34, in <module>
    from google.appengine.tools.docker import containers
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\docker\containers.py", line 47, in <module>
    import docker
ImportError: No module named docker
2015-03-05 19:11:27 (Process exited with code 1)
```

I even installed the latest Google Cloud SDK, but I'm getting the same error.

I'm able to install the [appengine SDK 1.9.18](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/downloads)(without using Google Cloud SDK) and able to run the project successfully.

This error is happening only for the App Engine launcher installed via Google Cloud SDK in Windows 7.

**This issue is raised in App Engine Issue Tracker: [Issue 125](http://code.google.com/p/google-cloud-sdk/issues/detail?id=125). I recommend you to star this issue.**

Comment: I don't have a Windows machine to check, but apparently `C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\lib\docker` did not install correctly -- can you check if that directory exists and what's in it?  Worst case, you should be able to get it from https://github.com/docker/docker-py ...

Comment: Yes Its there. I have installed the Google Cloud SDK in another system. Same issue there also.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is currently an issue with the dev_appserver bundled in the Cloud SDK.  A fix will be out soon.  In the meanwhile, your options are:
1) Use `gcloud preview app run` to run your app when using the Cloud SDK
2) Install the standalone AppEngine SDK (which you already mentioned in your question)

Comment: Wow, between this and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28626222/using-gcs-in-gae-local-devserver/), Google really dropped the ball on 1.9.18.  Please fix ASAP.

Comment: Is there a link to the Google bug tracker for this?  Would be useful to be able to raise the profile of this issue.

Comment: I installed the standalone AppEngine SDK as suggested, pointed my $PATH to it, but still get the same error.

Comment: I found I have to change the App Engine SDK path in the Preferences of the Google App Engine Launcher between the google-cloud-sdk and the AppEngine SDK, depending on whether I want to Deploy or run it on my own system respectively.

Answer (score 13):

This has happened to me today to reinstall the app engine sdk. I could not run my code in the launcher.

I remember reading that is not used pip app engine, but now I have solved the problem.

In short what I did was:

1. Install pip the footsteps of https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/installing.html (this also correctly install the setuptools)
2. Install docker-py by pip: pip install docker-py and ready, I can now run my code in the launcher

P.S.
Previously I tried to install the docker-py package, downloaded from https://github.com/docker/docker-py, but lacked setuptools, downloaded and installed the package did not work. So use this with pip.

Answer (score 3):

If installing docker-py doesn't work and the stacktrace shows that the error line is:

```
from docker import docker
```

Change this line to:

```
import docker
```

[Source](https://code.google.com/p/google-cloud-sdk/issues/detail?id=125#c17)

Answer (score 0):

Jumping on the answer from @Tzach and adding some info.

The file to modify is containers.py

for me it is located here :
C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\docker

If you can't modify it because the file is open in an application, it is in fact that the folder is protected. Just copy/paste the file on your desktop and modify it from there. then copy it back in the original folder.