# appengine ImportError: No module named docker

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have been trying to begin tutorial and launching the flask python using appengine launcher but getting the above error from the logs.

I downloaded the google cloud SDK installer and running the 'gcloud auth login' and 'gcloud components update gae-python', but when running the flask app using the launcher, I get the above error from the launcher's log.

I have re installed google cloud SDK but still the problem persist. I have even re installed python 64 bit.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28879485/unable-to-start-appengine-application-after-updating-it-via-google-cloud-sdk

Answer (score 0):

Try to install App Engine SDK and then see what happens. I had the same problem and after I have downloaded it everything went very well.
https://developers.google.com/appengine/downloads