# python appengine-gcs-client demo with local devserver hitting AccessTokenRefreshError(u'internal_failure',)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I'm having trouble getting the python appengine-gcs-client demo working using the 1.9.40 (latest presently) SDK's `dev_appserver.py`.

I followed the [Setting Up Google Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/googlecloudstorageclient/setting-up-cloud-storage) and the [App Engine and Google Cloud Storage Sample](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/googlecloudstorageclient/app-engine-cloud-storage-sample) instructions.

I created the default bucket for a paid app, with billing enabled and a non-zero daily spending limit set. I successfully uploaded a file to that bucket using the developer console.

I cloned the [GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-gcs-client](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-gcs-client) repo from github. I copied the `python/src/cloudstorage` dir into the `python/demo` dir, which now looks like this:

```
dancorn-laptop.acasa:/home/dancorn/src/appengine-gcs-client/python> find demo/ | sort
demo/
demo/app.yaml
demo/blobstore.py
demo/cloudstorage
demo/cloudstorage/api_utils.py
demo/cloudstorage/api_utils.pyc
demo/cloudstorage/cloudstorage_api.py
demo/cloudstorage/cloudstorage_api.pyc
demo/cloudstorage/common.py
demo/cloudstorage/common.pyc
demo/cloudstorage/errors.py
demo/cloudstorage/errors.pyc
demo/cloudstorage/__init__.py
demo/cloudstorage/__init__.pyc
demo/cloudstorage/rest_api.py
demo/cloudstorage/rest_api.pyc
demo/cloudstorage/storage_api.py
demo/cloudstorage/storage_api.pyc
demo/cloudstorage/test_utils.py
demo/__init__.py
demo/main.py
demo/main.pyc
demo/README
```

This is how I executed the devserver and the errors reported when trying to access http://localhost:8080 as instructed:

```
dancorn-laptop.acasa:/home/dancorn/src/appengine-gcs-client/python> /home/usr_local/google_appengine_1.9.40/dev_appserver.py demo
INFO     2016-08-04 01:07:51,786 sdk_update_checker.py:229] Checking for updates to the SDK.
INFO     2016-08-04 01:07:51,982 sdk_update_checker.py:257] The SDK is up to date.
INFO     2016-08-04 01:07:52,121 api_server.py:205] Starting API server at: http://localhost:50355
INFO     2016-08-04 01:07:52,123 dispatcher.py:197] Starting module "default" running at: http://localhost:8080
INFO     2016-08-04 01:07:52,124 admin_server.py:116] Starting admin server at: http://localhost:8000
INFO     2016-08-04 01:08:03,461 client.py:804] Refreshing access_token
INFO     2016-08-04 01:08:05,234 client.py:827] Failed to retrieve access token: {
  "error" : "internal_failure"
}
ERROR    2016-08-04 01:08:05,236 api_server.py:272] Exception while handling service_name: "app_identity_service"
method: "GetAccessToken"
request: "\n7https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.full_control"
request_id: "ccqdTObLrl"

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/usr_local/google_appengine_1.9.40/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/api_server.py", line 247, in _handle_POST
    api_response = _execute_request(request).Encode()
  File "/home/usr_local/google_appengine_1.9.40/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/api_server.py", line 186, in _execute_request
    make_request()
  File "/home/usr_local/google_appengine_1.9.40/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/api_server.py", line 181, in make_request
    request_id)
  File "/home/usr_local/google_appengine_1.9.40/google/appengine/api/apiproxy_stub.py", line 131, in MakeSyncCall
    method(request, response)
  File "/home/usr_local/google_appengine_1.9.40/google/appengine/api/app_identity/app_identity_defaultcredentialsbased_stub.py", line 192, in _Dynamic_GetAccessToken
    token = credentials.get_access_token()
  File "/home/usr_local/google_appengine_1.9.40/lib/oauth2client/oauth2client/client.py", line 689, in get_access_token
    self.refresh(http)
  File "/home/usr_local/google_appengine_1.9.40/lib/oauth2client/oauth2client/client.py", line 604, in refresh
    self._refresh(http.request)
  File "/home/usr_local/google_appengine_1.9.40/lib/oauth2client/oauth2client/client.py", line 775, in _refresh
    self._do_refresh_request(http_request)
  File "/home/usr_local/google_appengine_1.9.40/lib/oauth2client/oauth2client/client.py", line 840, in _do_refresh_request
    raise AccessTokenRefreshError(error_msg)
AccessTokenRefreshError: internal_failure

WARNING  2016-08-04 01:08:05,239 tasklets.py:468] suspended generator _make_token_async(rest_api.py:55) raised RuntimeError(AccessTokenRefreshError(u'internal_failure',))
WARNING  2016-08-04 01:08:05,240 tasklets.py:468] suspended generator get_token_async(rest_api.py:224) raised RuntimeError(AccessTokenRefreshError(u'internal_failure',))
WARNING  2016-08-04 01:08:05,240 tasklets.py:468] suspended generator urlfetch_async(rest_api.py:259) raised RuntimeError(AccessTokenRefreshError(u'internal_failure',))
WARNING  2016-08-04 01:08:05,240 tasklets.py:468] suspended generator run(api_utils.py:164) raised RuntimeError(AccessTokenRefreshError(u'internal_failure',))
WARNING  2016-08-04 01:08:05,240 tasklets.py:468] suspended generator do_request_async(rest_api.py:198) raised RuntimeError(AccessTokenRefreshError(u'internal_failure',))
WARNING  2016-08-04 01:08:05,241 tasklets.py:468] suspended generator do_request_async(storage_api.py:128) raised RuntimeError(AccessTokenRefreshError(u'internal_failure',))
ERROR    2016-08-04 01:08:05,241 main.py:62] AccessTokenRefreshError(u'internal_failure',)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dancorn/src/appengine-gcs-client/python/demo/main.py", line 43, in get
    self.create_file(filename)
  File "/home/dancorn/src/appengine-gcs-client/python/demo/main.py", line 89, in create_file
    retry_params=write_retry_params)
  File "/home/dancorn/src/appengine-gcs-client/python/demo/cloudstorage/cloudstorage_api.py", line 97, in open
    return storage_api.StreamingBuffer(api, filename, content_type, options)
  File "/home/dancorn/src/appengine-gcs-client/python/demo/cloudstorage/storage_api.py", line 697, in __init__
    status, resp_headers, content = self._api.post_object(path, headers=headers)
  File "/home/dancorn/src/appengine-gcs-client/python/demo/cloudstorage/rest_api.py", line 82, in sync_wrapper
    return future.get_result()
  File "/home/usr_local/google_appengine_1.9.40/google/appengine/ext/ndb/tasklets.py", line 383, in get_result
    self.check_success()
  File "/home/usr_local/google_appengine_1.9.40/google/appengine/ext/ndb/tasklets.py", line 427, in _help_tasklet_along
    value = gen.throw(exc.__class__, exc, tb)
  File "/home/dancorn/src/appengine-gcs-client/python/demo/cloudstorage/storage_api.py", line 128, in do_request_async
    deadline=deadline, callback=callback)
  File "/home/usr_local/google_appengine_1.9.40/google/appengine/ext/ndb/tasklets.py", line 427, in _help_tasklet_along
    value = gen.throw(exc.__class__, exc, tb)
  File "/home/dancorn/src/appengine-gcs-client/python/demo/cloudstorage/rest_api.py", line 198, in do_request_async
    follow_redirects=False)
  File "/home/usr_local/google_appengine_1.9.40/google/appengine/ext/ndb/tasklets.py", line 427, in _help_tasklet_along
    value = gen.throw(exc.__class__, exc, tb)
  File "/home/dancorn/src/appengine-gcs-client/python/demo/cloudstorage/api_utils.py", line 164, in run
    result = yield tasklet(**kwds)
  File "/home/usr_local/google_appengine_1.9.40/google/appengine/ext/ndb/tasklets.py", line 427, in _help_tasklet_along
    value = gen.throw(exc.__class__, exc, tb)
  File "/home/dancorn/src/appengine-gcs-client/python/demo/cloudstorage/rest_api.py", line 259, in urlfetch_async
    self.token = yield self.get_token_async()
  File "/home/usr_local/google_appengine_1.9.40/google/appengine/ext/ndb/tasklets.py", line 427, in _help_tasklet_along
    value = gen.throw(exc.__class__, exc, tb)
  File "/home/dancorn/src/appengine-gcs-client/python/demo/cloudstorage/rest_api.py", line 224, in get_token_async
    self.scopes, self.service_account_id)
  File "/home/usr_local/google_appengine_1.9.40/google/appengine/ext/ndb/tasklets.py", line 427, in _help_tasklet_along
    value = gen.throw(exc.__class__, exc, tb)
  File "/home/dancorn/src/appengine-gcs-client/python/demo/cloudstorage/rest_api.py", line 55, in _make_token_async
    token, expires_at = yield rpc
  File "/home/usr_local/google_appengine_1.9.40/google/appengine/ext/ndb/tasklets.py", line 513, in _on_rpc_completion
    result = rpc.get_result()
  File "/home/usr_local/google_appengine_1.9.40/google/appengine/api/apiproxy_stub_map.py", line 613, in get_result
    return self.__get_result_hook(self)
  File "/home/usr_local/google_appengine_1.9.40/google/appengine/api/app_identity/app_identity.py", line 519, in get_access_token_result
    rpc.check_success()
  File "/home/usr_local/google_appengine_1.9.40/google/appengine/api/apiproxy_stub_map.py", line 579, in check_success
    self.__rpc.CheckSuccess()
  File "/home/usr_local/google_appengine_1.9.40/google/appengine/api/apiproxy_rpc.py", line 157, in _WaitImpl
    self.request, self.response)
  File "/home/usr_local/google_appengine_1.9.40/google/appengine/ext/remote_api/remote_api_stub.py", line 201, in MakeSyncCall
    self._MakeRealSyncCall(service, call, request, response)
  File "/home/usr_local/google_appengine_1.9.40/google/appengine/ext/remote_api/remote_api_stub.py", line 235, in _MakeRealSyncCall
    raise pickle.loads(response_pb.exception())
RuntimeError: AccessTokenRefreshError(u'internal_failure',)
INFO     2016-08-04 01:08:05,255 module.py:788] default: "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 249
```

I was surprised when I saw the attempt to contact a Google server, I was expecting to use a faked, local filesystem-based emulation, based on these notes from the [App Engine and Google Cloud Storage Sample](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/googlecloudstorageclient/app-engine-cloud-storage-sample) instructions:

- [Using the client library with the development app server](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/googlecloudstorageclient/setting-up-cloud-storage#using_the_client_library_with_the_development_app_server):

> You can use the client library with the development server.
>
> ```
> **Note**: Files saved locally are subject to the file size and naming conventions imposed by the local filesystem.
> ```

- [app.yaml walkthrough](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/googlecloudstorageclient/app-engine-cloud-storage-sample#appyaml_walkthrough):

> You specify the project ID in the line application: your-app-id,
>   replacing the value your-app-id. This value isn't used when running
>   locally, but you must supply a valid project ID before deploying: the
>   deployment utility reads this entry to determine where to deploy your
>   app.

- [Deploying the Sample](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/googlecloudstorageclient/app-engine-cloud-storage-sample#deploying_the_sample), step 5:

> In your browser, visit https://.appspot.com; the
>   application will execute on page load, just as it did when running
>   locally. Only this time, the app will actually be writing to and
>   reading from a real bucket.

I even placed my real app's ID into the `app.yaml` file, but that didn't make any difference.

I've checked the known GAE issues and only found this potentially related one, but on a much older SDK version:

- [Issue 11690](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=11690) GloudStorage bug in GoogleAppEngineLanucher development server

I checked a few older SDK versions I have around (1.9.30, 1.9.35), just in case - no difference either.

My questions:

1. How can I make the GCS client operate locally (w/ faked GCS based on the local filesystem) when it's used with dev_appserver.py?
2. Since it's mentioned it should work with the real GCS as well even when used with dev_appserver.py what do I need to do to achieve that? (less important, more of a curiosity)

Comment: Ya, GCS client failed to upload files to staging bucket on running gae app locally. But on production, it works well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually the reason was what IMHO is a quite silly bug - inability to read the credentials from a local file written by an earlier version of the SDK (or related package?) and failure to fallback to a more decent action which leads to a rather misleading traceback throwing off the investigation.

Credit goes to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35890078/4495081 ('tho the bug mentioned in the post was for something else, ultimately triggering the similar end result)

After removing the `~/.config/gcloud/application_default_credentias.json` file the demo completed successfully using the local filesystem. And my real app worked fine as well.

My 2nd question stands, but I'm not too worried about it - personally I don't see a great value in using the real GCS storage with the local development server - I have to do testing on a real staging GAE app anyways for other reasons.