# Remote implementation for app_identity_service.GetAccessToken failed at GAE PHP dev

Tags: google-app-engine

Google App Engine SDK for PHP (at local environment) returns error on any try to use Google Cloud Storage. Error message is: 
`Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'google\appengine\runtime\RPCFailedError' with message 'Remote implementation for app_identity_service.GetAccessToken failed' in /media/data/home/vladimir/setup/gae/google_appengine/php/sdk/google/appengine/runtime/RemoteApiProxy.php on line 92`

It exactly repeats the problem described here:
[App engine update breaks CloudStorage in dev php env](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28625341/app-engine-update-breaks-cloudstorage-in-dev-php-env)
Test code from the question above shows the same result. 
I tried App Engine SDK for PHP versions 1.9.19, 1.9.20, 1.9.21 without success.

Answer (score 2):

On Win10 this issue can be solved by generating an application-default credentials file:

```
D:\Workspace\Sourcecode>gcloud auth application-default login
Credentials saved to file: [C:\Users\Otje\AppData\Roaming\gcloud\application_default_credentials.json]
```

And then setting the environment in commandline:

```
D:\Workspace\Sourcecode>SET GOOGLE_APPLICATION_DEFAULT=C:\Users\Otje\AppData\Roaming\gcloud\application_default_credentials.json
```

Seems to me GAE on local just outputs limited error information when it can't find the right credentials to succesfully connect to remote endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it was GAE's server side issue. They fixed it. I discovered that it started to work as expected today without any changes applied by me.